# Xamarin disable applications

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, command

Hello

I'm looking for resolve my problem. I want to disable application when I click button(for example Google Play will be disabled). I can do it from adb shell by command:

`pm disable "Application name"`

but when I want to do this from my application:

`Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new string[] { "su", "-c", "pm disable appName" });`

Nothing is changed, the app is still enabled. There is a way to disable application from code ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot enable or disable apps in this fashion(via code). The best you can probably do is open the subject application's information screen to have the user disable the application. It might be possible on a rooted device with elevated privileges/third party APIs, but I do not believe the Android SDK ships anything to do this.

This overall is an issue with permission levels as a system application would be able to do this, but not regular applications. You can only imagine how much power this would give regular applications if they could do this. The user should have say in what gets disabled/enabled on their phone. Thus pointing them in this direction is the best thing you can do.

Comment: So how works application like: Norton Family or ESET Parental Control
In Norton Family is avaiable blocking applications.

Comment: This is most likely a different type of workaround such as a custom launcher that only displays "Enabled flagged" applications that the "Parent" user accepts. This would also extend to a browser as well. They would need to create their own WebView to track items as well.

I have not used these apps, but I suspect that's what they do. If you look at the description of the store, you'll see:

IMPORTANT NOTE: Please disable any other browser and the YouTube app so that your children’s activity can be monitored.